# Quick sight adding nesting to SQL query which causes errors in Athena

Tags: amazon-athena, presto, amazon-quicksight

I'm trying to create a very simple visualisation in Quicksight, and to do this I'm using an SQL query in Quicksight,

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct uuid), day
FROM analytics.myTable
GROUP BY day
```

Unfortunately, whenever I run this query in Quicksight it fails due to the following error

> from the AWS Athena client. SYNTAX_ERROR: line 2:8: Column '_col0'
>   cannot be resolved

When I look in Athena, I can see that Quicksight is "nesting" the SQL query... this is what's causing the error in Athena,

```
/* QuickSight 4da449cf-ffc6-11e8-92ea-9ffafcc3adb3 */
SELECT "_col0"
FROM (SELECT COUNT(distinct uuid)
FROM pregnancy_analytics.final_test_parquet) AS "DAU"
```

What I don't understand is:
a) why this is flagging an error? 
b) why Quicksight is nesting the SQL?

If I simply run the command directly in Athena,

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct uuid) FROM analytics.myTable
```

It does indeed show the column name "_col0",

```
    _col0
1   1699174
```

so the fact that Quicksight is raising an error shouldn't actually be a problem.

Can someone offer some advice on how to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Please try adding an explicit column name: replace `COUNT(distinct uuid)` with `COUNT(distinct uuid) c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often in visualization software you will need to explicitly name your aggregate/function-wrapped columns as they default to things like _col0 which the software doesn't parse well, so it throws that error.

Specifically, I see this all the time in Superset using Presto.

For your problem explicitly, you should just do what Piotr recommended which is just adding a name after `COUNT(distinct uuid)` - I'm partial to freq, but it looks like you'll want something like uuid or unique_uuid :)

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the query to explicitly name the aggregated column and then the query will work.

Example:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct uuid) as "distinct_uuid", day
FROM analytics.myTable
GROUP BY day
```